# How to pass state from one functional component to another which is being rendered by a button component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Suppose I have component1 which has a state that I want to share with component2, now component2 is being rendered by a button component (not html button) by using useHistory hook. Now using the context API, my button component has access to the state of component1 by using context provider but how can I access the state from component2. All components are functional components.